# Wordpress + bootstrap посты в несколько строк

Tags: php, wordpress, bootstrap

Вывожу посты используя такой код:

```
<div class="row">
                <?php
                $args = array("category"=>3, "nopaging"=>4, "orderby"=>"date", "order"=>"ASC");
                $posts = get_posts($args);
                foreach($posts as $post){setup_postdata($post); ?>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 serviceItem">
                        <div class="imgBox">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail("service-thumb"); ?>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="textBox">
                            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                            <?php echo content(20); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php } wp_reset_postdata();?>
            </div>
```

Возможно ли вывести посты так, что бы создавался row с двумя постами, потом второй row со следующими двумя постами....? Прошу помощи.

Answer (score 1):

Взять переменную и проверять в цикле делится ли на 2 -> выводить закрывающий и открывающий

```
</div><div class="row">
```